# Can NumPy arrays and lists be modified in Python functions?

Tags: python, numpy

Do NumPy arrays and lists get modified in Python functions? If yes, then how to take care that the values are not modified?

Comment: See [`numpy.ndarray.flags`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html) for information on setting the `WRITEABLE` flag of a NumPy array.  But note that you can't prevent a function from modifying the array if it really wants to--the function could just change the flag.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but to avoid modification of arrays/lists , you can use `list_name.copy()` or `deepcopy()`.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, those objects are mutable.**

Be careful to write [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function): pass in what the function needs and return what it produces. Don't use global variables and be careful not to produce side-effects if possible (plotting and printing things is okay, if that's the goal of the function). If you need to mutate an object in-place, make a copy of it inside the function. Aim for calling code that looks like this:

```py
transformed_list = transform_function(original_list)
```

The `original_list` object should be unchanged after this operation. This is how most Pandas and NumPy code works, so it's how most people expect other code to work too.

Answer (score 1):

> Do NumPy arrays and lists get modified in Python functions?

**Yes**.  In Python, a function can change its mutable arguments, and these changes will persist after the function call.  (In Python, you should generally keep in mind whether a type is mutable or immutable for this reason.)

> If yes, then how to take care that the values are not modified?

**This isn't necessary**, although it's an option you might want to use. It's also often inefficient, especially for large numeric arrays.  Even in pure Python, some built-in function, such as [`sort`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/sort.html), mutate their arguments.  On the Numpy side of things, even simple functions like [`add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add) often have a mechanism to do the calculation in-place, without creating a new array.

Instead, the Python standard is: if a function mutates the arguments then is should return `None`.  Also, returning `None` helps avoid the common gotcha problem of [mutable default arguments](https://dollardhingra.com/blog/python-mutable-default-arguments/), although there are other ways to avoid that too.